# equivalent to MATLAB's diff function in Numpy, getting unexpected outcomes

Tags: python, pandas, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to re-write a MATLAB function I wrote in Python

When calculating the difference between consecutive elements in an array of dtype float64 in Numpy using np.diff(array) or np.ediff1d(array), I get results that are nonsensical to me (eg1 is the output). When I convert the array to a Pandas series and use pd.Series.diff(), I get the correct results (eg2), but I'm not used to working with Pandas and would prefer to obtain the desired result in Numpy. To wit, I'd quite like to know why Numpy behaves like this lol.

```
 mididiff = np.diff(midi)
```

or

```
 mididiff = np.ediff1d(midi)
```

both result in output1 (further below), which doesn't make sense to me

if I convert midi to a pandas Series:

```
midi = pd.Series(midi)
```

then calculate the difference:

```
mididiff = midi.diff()
```

results in output2 (further below)

output1:

```
diff
array([ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  6.97604821e+01,  4.23796132e-01,  2.64797469e-02,
        1.30111704e-02,  3.69745669e-02,  4.19431796e-02,  1.30448709e-02,
       -1.72452049e-04,  1.26183770e-02,  3.21393846e-03, -7.44549242e-03,
       -7.03518633e-03, -3.50274566e-03, -1.40289148e-02, -1.60362681e-02,...
        1.74323138e-02,  3.03912899e-02,  1.10621339e-02,  2.01706584e-02,
        1.25640437e-02,  1.51559658e-02,  1.41538434e-02,  9.03407863e-03])
```

output2:

```
0            NaN
1       0.000000
2       0.000000
3       0.000000
4       0.000000
5       0.000000
6       0.000000
7       0.000000
8       0.000000
9       0.000000
10     69.760482
11      0.423796
12      0.026480
13      0.013011

         ...    
787     0.011062
788     0.020171
789     0.012564
790     0.015156
791     0.014154
792     0.009034
```

output2 is the expected data, but I haven't worked with pandas yet 
and obtaining these results in a numpy array would really move 
things along. I'm aware that the datatype in output1 is clearly a 
gap in my knowledge (in my defence I'm a saxophone player by trade!).

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What is wrong?  Can you show it with small array (of integers)?  I think `np.diff` is python code which you can view.

Comment: *"I get results that are nonsensical to me"*  Explain exactly what is unexpected about the output that you show.  Except for the `nan` that Pandas adds at the beginning, output1 and output2 look like the same values.  The output is *formatted* differently, but that is because numpy arrays and Pandas DataFrames use different formats for their printed output.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The outputted data represents changes in musical pitch from a recording I made and I knew what to expect, hence output2 made sense to me. I'd failed to identify that the numpy output was essentially the same, I just saw what I thought were the wrong values and panicked. Thanks so much for the clarification, appreciated.

Comment: At its core `np.diff` is just doing (for a 1d array) `a[1:] - a[:-1]`, producing an array that is one element shorter.  In MATLAB terms that's `a(2:end) - a(1:(end-1))`